# Nesting a Tablayout With Fragments as Child fragments inside an Fragment from Navigation drawer

Tags: java, android

I have  implemented a Navigation drawer with Fragments Frag_A , Frag_B , Frag_C and Frag_D successfully, But I want inside Fragment B to put A Tablayout  with  3 TABS (Child Fragments) child_Frag_1, child_Frag_2, child_Frag_3

Any Links on how to succesfully achive this with child_Frag_1, child_Frag_2 and child_Frag_1 displaying the content

Answer (score 1):

You can use TabLayout as parent to your TabItems with FrameLayout to hold the actual fragment :

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout  
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:background="#7367">  
  
        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:text="Home" />  
  
        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:text="Java" />  
  
        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:text="Android" />  
  
        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:text="Php" />  
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>  
  
    <FrameLayout  
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:layout_height="455dp"  
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"  
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"  
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout">  
  
    </FrameLayout>  
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

For better understanding and for the other detail on how you navigate through your tabs , see this simple [tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-tablayout-with-framelayout) that use the same thing you want to do , except the drawer , which make no problem , you can treat the fragment that host the TabLayout as normal activity like in this tutorial .

**Note :** I highly recommend you to use the new navigation component of Android Jetpack Architecture in this cases , it handle all the TROUBLE for you , like navigating and handling the backstack and a lot of other benfits , you can check the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/navigation) for more info about it .

**Enjoy !**

Comment: Thank you the layout are populated using an adapter

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Adapters. You just need to create 1 layout and the adapter will reflect as many layouts or views as you want. You can learn a lot about adapters on the internet.